# how add text and icon inside TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to make the text and icon inside TextFormField
this is my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfheI.png)

```
_FormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          print("test");
        }
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        fillColor: kPrimaryLightColor,
        filled: true,
        focusColor: kPrimaryLightColor,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            borderSide: BorderSide.none),
        //hintText: 'Email'
        //hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),
        labelText: 'Email',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
        //icon: Icon(Icons.email),
        icon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
      ),
    );
  }
```

i want it like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTcCV.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `prefixIcon` and `suffixIcon` of `inputDecoration` to add icons inside the field. If you want the field label only within the field and not as a label above it, specify only `hintText` and leave out `LabelText`. Check the following code, you can wrap the icons inside a `Padding` if you need more space.

```
TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          print("test");
        }
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
        fillColor: Colors.grey,
        filled: true,
        focusColor: Colors.blue,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            borderSide: BorderSide.none),
        hintText: 'Email',
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

your can use prefixIcon and suffixIcon which takes widget. In which you can give Icon to the prefixIcon and to the suffixIcon you can give IconButton in which you can give the logic to hide/show password. To implement the logic declare a boolean variable which is used for if the password is to be shown or hidden. the logic must be like this.

```
bool showPassword=false;
_FormField() {
    return TextFormField(
       obscureText: !showPassword,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          print("test");
        }
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
suffixIcon:IconButton(icon:showPassword?Icon(Icons.lock):Icon(Icons.lock_open),
onPressed:(){
setState(() {
      showPassword=!showPassword;
   });
}
)
  ),
    );
  }
```

The code is not formatted well sorry for that I write it manual here

Comment: @LAmer if this answer solved your problem please accept it and upvote the answer. Thank You